# I created a Unmanaged package and uploaded...but while installing got this error

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, professional-edition

I have created a Unmanaged package with objects and other components. There is 1 page, 1 class and 1 test class in that package.

When i try to install that package in Professional edition...i get this error : [image]

Its giving the error to only Test class that i have added recently.Test class code:-

```
@isTest
public class attachPDFToInvoiceTest {
   static testMethod void TestPDFToInvoice() {
       Project__c Proj = new Project__c();
       Proj.Project_Title__c = 'Test Project';
       Proj.Location__c = 'Test Location';
       Proj.Total_Amount__c = 0;
       Insert Proj;

       Invoice__c Inv = new Invoice__c();
       Inv.Project__c = Proj.id;
       Insert Inv;

       Test.setCurrentPage(Page.pdfDemo);

       attachPDFToInvoice PDFToInvo = new attachPDFToInvoice(new ApexPages.StandardController(Inv));
       PDFToInvo.attachPDF();  
    }  
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot create apex class in professional edition(Platform limitation) and we can't install a package which has apex class in it unless that package is from app exchange.

So you can't install a normal unmanage package in professional edition.

As from docs:

> Your app can contain business logic such as classes, triggers, email
>   services, etc. written in Apex. As a general rule, Apex is not
>   supported in GE/PE, so it will not run in these editions. However,
>   Apex developed as part of an ISV app and included in a managed package
>   can run in GE/PE, even though those editions do not support Apex by
>   default.
>
> You must be an eligible partner with salesforce.com and your app has
>   to pass the security review. The appropriate permissions will
>   automatically be enabled after you pass the security review.

[Using Apex in Group and Professional Editions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm)

Comment: Thanks for reply :)  I read this content on many sites today....So i created a managed package from that unmanaged package....but when i tried to install that package i got the same error.

Comment: Can you please explain "However, Apex developed as part of an ISV app" part also how do i check if i am eligible partner with salesforce and how to pass the security review.

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar You need to submit your app for app exchange. Anybody can create and submit App on App exchange.